# Moq returning different object from Setup

Tags: c#, moq

Can you please tell the scenario when the object returned could be different from the setup object?

The `Object Id` set during debugging in `Setup` is different when src code is executed.

```
interface IBaseClass
{
    IFactory aFactory;
}

class Point
{
    Point(int x, int y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    int x;
    int y;
}

interface Factory
{
    public AnObject create(string a, Point pt);
}
```

Test Code

```
var anObjectMock = new Mock<AnObject> { DefaultValue = DefaultValue.Mock };

var sMatcher = It.Is<string>(s => s.Equals("aString"));
var ptMatcher = It.Is<Point>(p => (p.x == CONST_X && p.y == CONST_Y));

var FactoryMock = Mock.Get<IFactory>(IBaseClassMock.Object.Factory);
FactoryMock.Setup(f => f.create(sMatcher, ptMatcher)).Returns(anObjectMock.Object); // Say ObjectId is #1
```

SRC

```
Object obj = BasicImaging.Factory.create("aString", new Point(CONST_X, CONST_Y)); 
// Getting no ObjectId
```

Answer (score 0):

Is `BasicImaging.Factory` an actual mock (`IBaseClassMock.Factory`)? I think no.

You need to inject your mock into `BasicImaging.Factory` so it uses you mock instead of the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `BasicImaging.Factory` you should use `IBaseClassMock.Object.Factory` (that is, the mock you have set up).

Comment: @Azodious, but what is your `BasicImaging` exactly? Also, please use `camelCase` for variables, and `PascalCase` for types - that would make it *much* easier to read.